# Getting 0 when I enter my inputs

Tags: java, input

My goal is to input three numbers and have the program spit out the middle number.  This works fine for doing a `System.out.println`, but when I have to use `JOptionPane` it starts to get messy.

Here's the code I've got:

```
public class ReturnMiddle {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num1 = 0;
    int num2 = 0;
    int num3 = 0;
    int smallest = returnMiddle(num1, num2, num3);

    String inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your first number?");
    num1 = (Integer.parseInt(inputValue));

    inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your second number?");
    num2 = (Integer.parseInt(inputValue));

    inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your third number?");
    num3 = (Integer.parseInt(inputValue));

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, smallest);

}

    public static int returnMiddle(int num1, int num2, int num3) {

        //Returns the smaller of num1 and num2.
        int middle12 = Math.min(num1, num2);

        //Returns the smaller of num2 and num3.
        int middle23 = Math.min(num2, num3);

        //Returns the smaller of num1 and num3.
        int middle13 = Math.min(num1, num3);

        //Returns the larger of middle12 and middle13.
        int middleNumber1 = Math.max(middle12, middle13);

        //Returns the larger of middleNumber1 and middle23, which
        //ends up being the middle of the original 3 numbers.
        int middleNumber2 = Math.max(middleNumber1, middle23);

        //Makes the method "returnMiddle" return middleNumber2.
        return middleNumber2;

    }

}
```

When I unput the three numbers, I get 0 each time.  Is this an issue with using `num1`, `num2`, and `num3` in the two different methods?  Am I calling the `returnMiddle` method wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You must use the method at the right place.
Currently you calculate the result FIRST and get the Input SECOND. You have to do it the other way round.

```
// dont calculate it here

String inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your first number?");
num1 = (Integer.parseInt(inputValue));

inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your second number?");
num2 = (Integer.parseInt(inputValue));

inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your third number?");
num3 = (Integer.parseInt(inputValue));

// you have to calculate the middle one here.
int middle = returnMiddle(num1, num2, num3);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, middle);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the returnMiddle wrong. It should be called after you read and assign the inputs.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
int num3 = 0;
int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

String inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your first number?");
num1 = (Integer.parseInt(inputValue));

inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your second number?");
num2 = (Integer.parseInt(inputValue));

inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your third number?");
num3 = (Integer.parseInt(inputValue));

smallest = returnMiddle(num1, num2, num3);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, smallest);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

looking at your code you have

> int smallest = returnMiddle(num1, num2, num3);

here you are actually telling the compiler that you want the var 'smallest' to be equal to the result of the returnMiddle function. since the user inputs are after calling that method, you are not passing those values to that function on that call, but actually the initialized 0:

int smallest = returnMiddle(0,0,0);

You will need to call the method after you get the user inputs.